# Invalid register for .seh_savexmm\r using theano with MinGW

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, theano, spyder

When I run the file in Spyder, following error message was shown.

> Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', forall_inplace,cpu,scan_fn&scan_fn&scan_fn&scan_fn&scan_fn}(Shape_i{0}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, , , , , AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0, , , , , AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0, , , , , AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0, , , , , AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0, , , , , AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0, AllocDiag.0), '\n', 'The following error happened while compiling the node', Elemwise{Composite{((scalar_sigmoid(i0) * i1) + (scalar_sigmoid(i2) * tanh(i3)))}}(Gemm{inplace}.0, , Gemm{inplace}.0, Gemm{no_inplace}.0), '\n', 'Compilation failed (return status=1): C:\Users\uos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOVbwzm.s: Assembler messages:\r. C:\Users\uos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOVbwzm.s:2133: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm\r. ', '[Elemwise{Composite{((scalar_sigmoid(i0) * i1) + (scalar_sigmoid(i2) * tanh(i3)))}}(, , , )]')

I'm working on Anaconda / Python 2.7 / MinGW-w64/ Theano 1.0.2

I think "Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm\r." is the important part.

With some search, I assume this can be solved by disabling optimization of the GCC. Is it right?

There are two possible suggested solutions for similar problems:
1) -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables compiler option
2) disabling Dispatched CPU optimizations by passing the -DCPU_DISPATCH= flag to CMake.

I cannot figure out how to set up the options. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: I'd say you have to recompile Theano to pass `-DCPU_DISPATCH` and disable GCC optimizations for it. You can take a look at conda-build and conda-forge to see how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please advise me of how to pass the option to Theano?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't compiled Theano before. My advice is for you to fork Theano's conda-forge recipe, modify it as you need and use conda-build to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem, I think maybe I have solved it.
I try to find the code that compile the network in theano, I find it is in /site-packges/theano/gof/cmodule.py.
I guess that the cxxflags is the parameters that will be passed to gcc, I add

```
cxxflags.append('-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables')
```

in line 2191. Maybe you can try my way.